# Fetching data from multiple table based on comma separated keys in mysql laravel5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4, query-builder

I have a table called industry table

---

id     |  name

1         IT

2         Banking

3         Telecom

I have another table called jobs table

---

id    |    job_title     |  industry

45         AsstManager     2,3

46         soft.dev        1,3

---

Now how do I search all the jobs in banking and telecom industry?
**I am using laravel5.4 query builder.**
I am really clueless, how can  I approach this keeping in mind the performance also.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You've made a mistake by saving your relations as comma separated values. This is a huge headache. You should have used a mapping table for this many to many relationship. I would recommend you address that first.

Comment: If you want to keep performance in the mind and also you would like to avoid using raw sql, then you need to change the design of your data structure not to use comma separated values in a single field. See this SO question for detsils: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad